# mongodb db.collection.runCommand("text",{"search":"search text"}) using c++

Tags: mongodb

how to execute this command:

db.collection.runCommand("text",{"search":"search text"})

using c++ in mongodb.

I can already connect to the database.

Comment: Basically construct the BSON form for "command". If you have MongoDB 2.6 or greater though, this is a standard query with the `$text` operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I followed the "BSON" way and do it like this:
session->get().runCommand("ide", BSON("text"<<"sems"<<"search"<< value), result);

And it succeeded! Thank you very much!